# Merge Single Record XMLs into Multi-Record XML using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to merge multiple single record XML files into a single XML with multiple records with PowerShell. I'm new to PowerShell but found some decent documents on merging XML but I have been unable to make them work.  I need help figuring out what I have done incorrectly.

I have pasted the PowerShell script below, it runs with no errors but only outputs the data from the first XML document (XMLRecord01.xml) Examples of source files and expected output are at the end of the post.

### POWERSHELL SCRIPT

```
[xml]$XML01 = Get-Content -Path 'C:\TEMP\XMLRecord01.xml'
[xml]$XML02 = Get-Content -Path 'C:\TEMP\XMLRecord02.xml'


$Nodes2Add = $XML02.SelectNodes("XMLHost")

foreach($XMLHost in $Nodes2Add)
{
    $Node = $XML02.ImportNode($XMLHost, $false)
    $XML01.AppendChild($Node)
}

$XML01.Save('C:\temp\XMLMergeTest.txt')
```

### SAMPLE INPUT/OUTPUT FILES

```
******  XML 1  ******
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TESTDataSet> 
  <Header>
    <HD01_01>HeaderData</HD01_01>
    <HD01_03>HeaderData</HD01_03>
    <HD01_04>HeaderData</HD01_04>
    <HD01_07>HeaderData</HD01_07>
    <HD01_08>HeaderData</HD01_08>
     <Record>
      <RD01>
        <RD01_01>UniqueRecordID.001</RD01_01>
        <RD01_02>Record001DATA</RD01_02>
        <RD01_03>Record001DATA</RD01_03>
        <RD01_04>Record001DATA</RD01_04>
      </RD01>
      <RD02>
        <RD02_01>MoreData4RecordID.001</RD02_01>
        <RD02_02>Record001DATA</RD02_02>
        <RD02_03>Record001DATA</RD02_03>
        <RD02_04>Record001DATA</RD02_04>
        <RD02_05>Record001DATA</RD02_05>
      </RD02>
     </Record>
  </Header>
</TESTDataSet>

****** XML2  ******
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TESTDataSet> 
  <Header>
    <HD01_01>HeaderData</HD01_01>
    <HD01_03>HeaderData</HD01_03>
    <HD01_04>HeaderData</HD01_04>
    <HD01_07>HeaderData</HD01_07>
    <HD01_08>HeaderData</HD01_08>
     <Record>
      <RD01>
        <RD01_01>UniqueRecordID.002</RD01_01>
        <RD01_02>Record002DATA</RD01_02>
        <RD01_03>Record002DATA</RD01_03>
        <RD01_04>Record002DATA</RD01_04>
      </RD01>
      <RD02>
        <RD02_01>MoreData4RecordID.002</RD02_01>
        <RD02_02>Record002DATA</RD02_02>
        <RD02_03>Record002DATA</RD02_03>
        <RD02_04>Record002DATA</RD02_04>
        <RD02_05>Record002DATA</RD02_05>
      </RD02>
    </Record>
  </Header>
</TESTDataSet>


****** EXPECTED COMBINED XML ******
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TESTDataSet> 
  <Header>
    <HD01_01>HeaderData</HD01_01>
    <HD01_03>HeaderData</HD01_03>
    <HD01_04>HeaderData</HD01_04>
    <HD01_07>HeaderData</HD01_07>
    <HD01_08>HeaderData</HD01_08>
     <Record>
      <RD01>
        <RD01_01>UniqueRecordID.001</RD01_01>
        <RD01_02>Record001DATA</RD01_02>
        <RD01_03>Record001DATA</RD01_03>
        <RD01_04>Record001DATA</RD01_04>
      </RD01>
      <RD02>
        <RD02_01>MoreData4RecordID.001</RD02_01>
        <RD02_02>Record001DATA</RD02_02>
        <RD02_03>Record001DATA</RD02_03>
        <RD02_04>Record001DATA</RD02_04>
        <RD02_05>Record001DATA</RD02_05>
      </RD02>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <RD01>
        <RD01_01>UniqueRecordID.002</RD01_01>
        <RD01_02>Record002DATA</RD01_02>
        <RD01_03>Record002DATA</RD01_03>
        <RD01_04>Record002DATA</RD01_04>
      </RD01>
      <RD02>
        <RD02_01>MoreData4RecordID.002</RD02_01>
        <RD02_02>Record002DATA</RD02_02>
        <RD02_03>Record002DATA</RD02_03>
        <RD02_04>Record002DATA</RD02_04>
        <RD02_05>Record002DATA</RD02_05>
      </RD02>
    </Record>
  </Header>
</TESTDataSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping through the individual nodes seems a bit excessive.

Why not concatenate those two files, bring them in as a single XML object, and then removeChild('')?

Comment: That might work for this one example but with the real data that might not be an efficient approach. Might be more that needs to be removed. This is still an answer altough the OPs approach does not seem _excessive_

Comment: This is just one piece of a larger script.  The final goal is to monitor a folder, merge all the XMLs (sometimes hundreds) found and output a single XML for processing.  The actual files are more complex than the examples given but I didn't what to confuse the issue.